# Django ModelForms, override a field, keep the same label

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

In my ModelForm, I have to override some settings of the fields (e.g. `choices`, or `required` state). This requires declaring the entire field again as formfield.

Is there a simple way to access the `verbose_name` of the model field, so this doesn't have to redefined?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have to redefine the field to change these settings. You can access the field in the form `__init__` like below.

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta(object):
        model = MyModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['my_field'].required = True
```

Comment: Totally awesome, even a better fix for the problem!